# On a motherboard spec, what does the x8 mean in "1 x PCIe 3.0 x16 (x8 Bandwidth)"?

Tags: motherboard

Motherboards I'm looking at list their expansion slots as:

```
3 x PCI (32 bit)
1 x PCIe 3.0 x16
1 x PCIe 3.0 x16 (x8 Bandwidth)
```

What does the x8 bandwidth bit mean, and shouldn't both of the PCIe 3.0 slots be the same?

How can such a motherboard be advertised as 'quad SLI' if it has to use three different types of slot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If this is a full and complete list of slots**, then the motherboard **can not** do Quad SLI.

It can do SLI (2 cards) only.
The second slot although is physically x16 it only provides 8x worth of bandwidth.

If you put 2 high end video cards like nvidia 680,690,780,790, titian or ati radeon 6870,6890,7970, or 7990 then the second card will, in some cases, not have enough bandwidth to run at full speed.

If you use lower video cards the difference is minimal.

Comment: Treu. The difference for most cards seems to be in the 2-8% region (depending per app/game, and usually a lot less with mid- or entry-level cards).

Comment: The motherboard is this one: http://www.scan.co.uk/products/asrock-z87-extreme3-intel-z87-s-1150-ddr3-sata-iii-sata-raid-pcie-30-%28x16%29-d-sub-dvi-d-hdmi-atx which states quad SLI.

Comment: The board you linked to has the following PCIe connectors: • 2 x PCIe 3.0 x16, • 1 x PCIe 2.0 x1. IN theory you could use two cards in the x16 slots (at x8 speed, which should be more then enough for anything but the most Über monster cards) and a single x1 slot. That one is fast enough for a graphics card for office use, but it seriously lacks for gaming (it has 1/16th of the speed of the other slots. Usually you want at least four times that bandwidth.)

Comment: @SLC The motherboard can not do Quad SLI period, it is an error made by the human entering the data.  If you used single slot video card and accepted a huge performance loss with the pcie 2.0 x1 slot you could get 3 not 4.  The board supports 2 high end dual slot video cards.

Answer (score 4):

3 x PCI (32 bit)
1 x PCIe 3.0 x16
1 x PCIe 3.0 x16 (x8 Bandwidth)

> What does the x8 bandwidth bit mean, and shouldn't both of the PCIe 3.0 slots be the same?

It means that the motherboard has 16 (version 3) PCIe lanes and two connectors. You can either use one connector and it will connect all sixteen lanes, or use two of the slots and each slot will be aloocated 8 of the sixteen lanes.

In graphics:

```
16 lines                   /--- PCIe connector (x16)
from CPU -- Motherboard -- 
                           \--- PCIe connector (not used)

or as 


16 lines                   /--- PCIe connector (x8 used)
from CPU -- Motherboard -- 
                           \--- PCIe connector (x8 used)
```

This part has nothing to do with SLI or even graphics. You can use two PCie cards; e.g. SATA3 cards, RAID cards, audio cards, network cards, graphics card, ...

(Any PCIe card will do, including, but not limited to graphics.)

> How can such a motherboard be advertised as 'quad SLI' if it has to use
>   three different types of slot?

Your post only shows to different kinds of slots. The ancient [PCI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conventional_PCI) bus, which is old. The PCI configuration used in most PCs is 33Mhz, 32 bit which barely has enough speed to fill a single Gbit NIC. It should never be used unless you have some old low bandwidth cards (e.g. serial cards, parallel port cards, USB1 card, old audio card, ...)

The other 'slot' you mention is PCIe. It is the modern interface. It is a point to point connection (which means each lane has its own speed, while PCI is a bus and the max speed is shared by all devices).  Basically you only want to use this. The PCI slots are just wasted space.

As to quad SLI: I guess you could put two dual GPU cards in the PCIe v3 slots, but without knowing which motherboard you are referring to all we can do is guess.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply when using SLI, you're not using the x16 as a x16 connector - you're using it at x8 speed. You can have a maximum of two cards, with 2 processors each for 4 processors in SLI.

the x16 refers to an x16 *physical* connector, with 16 pcie lanes, while the x16/x8 is a x16 *physical* connector with only 8 lanes.

Comment: If the maximum is 2, what is quad SLI?

Comment: 2 video cards with 2 processors each I'd guess. There's internal SLI between the processors in one card, and the two cards are connected over a SLI bridge.

Comment: If I google quad SLI I get pictures of machines with 4 cards in...

Comment: In which case it might help to give specific motherboards as an example.

Comment: http://www.scan.co.uk/products/asrock-z87-extreme3-intel-z87-s-1150-ddr3-sata-iii-sata-raid-pcie-30-%28x16%29-d-sub-dvi-d-hdmi-atx